# Are there words missing from these phrases?

Tags: grammar

> The cancellation of the Immigrant Investor Program, announced
>   ***Wednesday***, is ***the latest*** in a series of moves by Ottawa that have been
>   perceived ***in parts of China and even Canada*** as limiting the inflow of
>   Chinese people and investment into the country.

It seems that many words I would expect to be there are left out around the highlighted phrases:

1: why use just "Wednesday", not "on Wednesday"?

2: Does "the latest" leave out "move"?

3: Does "in parts of China and even Canada" mean "in parts of China and in parts of even Canada"?

Comment: It's best if you ask only one question per question.  Q2: Yes, you can insert *move* if you really want to, though it's less idiomatic.  Q3: It's ambiguous, but I read it as [in [parts of China] and [even Canada]], not [in parts of [[China] and [even Canada]]].

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it contains multiple unrelated questions.

Comment: I don't know that they're completely unrelated questions. The common thread is the "missing" words. It seems to me the overall question is about sentence parts implied by the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

For days of the week, it is acceptable to omit "on" in most situations. Because the days of the week are unique, proper names and they are used so frequently to describe when an action is taking place, saying "announced Wednesday" means the same thing as "announced on Wednesday."

It sounds like this text might be part of a newspaper article, in which case word count matters.

**Question 2**

In this context, "the latest" takes on a noun role, standing in for "the latest move." This kind of construction is often formulated "The [superlative adjective as noun] in a [collection] of [things]." To say "the latest move in a series of moves" is clear and correct English, but the use of "move" (or any noun or verb) twice in close proximity in the sentence is not generally good English style (English speakers tend to either omit redundant words or use synonyms).

Some parallel examples:

- Last week's slam dunk was the last in a series of victories for the Chicago Bulls.
- This morning's brawl in Times Square was the first in a rash of fist fights that spread through downtown New York.

**Question 3**

The writer assumes that it would not be surprising for people in parts of China to perceive the cancellation of an immigration program as limiting the inflow of Chinese people into Canada. However, he does assume that it might be surprising to know that people in parts of Canada itself also perceive the cancellation of that program in the same way.

If both parts of China and Canada were equally likely to perceive the cancellation in this way, then the writer would have omitted the word "even" and just wrote "in parts of China and Canada", or if there were other countries involved, "in parts of China, Canada, and the United States," for example. The use of "even" here acts to emphasize the writer's acknowledgement that the reader might find it surprising that parts of Canada view this event in a similar light to those in China.